# My screen or a window flashes once in a while, even when I don't do anything. Any idea how I could fix this?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, graphics, ubuntu-gnome

I just got a new server (Supermicro X11DPH-T) with a new NVidia card (RTX 2060) and a ton of RAM (512Gb ECC).

The motherboard has 2 processors and the video board must be accessed by CPU 2 (at least according to the docs). I've not seen anything in Linux that would in any way mention that specific *feature*.

That being said, it works great, the boot process is slow, but once I'm in X-Windows / Gnome, it looks good.

However, once in a while (although, quite often) I get a black or a white flash. It makes me think of the flash used to *represent a beep* (Visual Alert, see screenshot below). For example, when I push the "Backspace" once at an empty prompt, it beeps. However, as far as I know I turned that feature off so it should not happen. Also it happens in other windows, not the current window (including the Nautilus! [is the graphical shell still called Nautilus under 18.04 Gnome?])

To me it feels like that other window is getting updated and the code will somehow miss the VBL and the refresh happens *at the wrong time* (i.e. I see the `glClear()` and further render.) Everything looks just fine before and after the flash which is very short. It's just that it's rather annoying!

Has anyone experience a similar flashing *effect* and would there be things I can try to prevent further flashing?

Additional note: the flash doesn't *leak*. It happens in a specific window and does not overlap to other windows in any way (it happened enough time that I could see that the clipping works as expected).

[image]